# how to login in EC2 instance with non ec2-user?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to login with non ec2-user account in amazon linux ami?

```
#useradd -m sample
#passwd sample
 set password

#cat /etc/passwd
sample:x:508:1002::/home/monitor/sample:/bin/bash

# cat /home/monitor/sample/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="echo 'Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root
user.';echo;sleep10"    ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxx

# chown -R sample /home/monitor/sample/.ssh
```

I copied /root/.ssh/authorized_keys to the new user's .ssh directory also

At login time server says 'server refused our key' and no supported authentication method available popup.

How to associate sample with my existing key pair?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You copied the root keys, and not the ec2-user keys. You should copy those keys and then ensure you've set the proper permissions.

> cp -r ~ec2-user/.ssh ~sample
>
> chown -R sample:sample ~sample/.ssh
>
> chmod 700 ~sample/.ssh
>
> chmod 600 ~sample/.ssh/authorized_keys

If this doesn't fix the problem, run a verbose ssh connection, and paste the results (removing any pertinent info)

> ssh -i [keyfile] [user]@[ip] -v

and I'll try to help more.

Comment: ~ in linux terms means home you can go ~$user instead of typing /home/$user

Comment: Tried to do this via Cloud-init for two days. This answer saved my week & deadline!

Answer (score 1):

All i can say is be very very careful when you try this,  this first time i did i ended up locking myself out of my instance completely.  i followed the instructions here:

http://utkarshsengar.com/2011/01/manage-multiple-accounts-on-1-amazon-ec2-instance/

and got it to work on the second try.  whatever you do make sure you stay logged in with the ec2-user until you can verify that you can actually get in with the new user you create

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this blog, where it given procedure for adding new user to instance for login into the instance with newly created user.

[how to add new user for login into amazon-ec2 instance](https://shahumang.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/how-to-add-new-user-for-login-to-amazon-ec2-centos-instance/)